# QEMU guest Ubuntu cannot use external webcam

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, webcam, qemu

I recently set up guest Ubuntu 18.04 with QEMU on my host Mac OS 11.4 (2019 13 inches). To save the trouble of installing a driver for FaceTime camera, I bought an external webcam [this one specifically](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B088PYMBTT).

I configured the webcam host-to-guest passing with this code (also tried using bus id and device id):
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpRXb.png)

I can see my camera device connected when I run lsusb on the Ubuntu though it is unnamed.
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTZbM.png)

Cheese cannot find my camera. running player tv:// doesn't work either. running gphoto2 --auto-detect finds nothing.

Running dmesg gives this error:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoqVD.jpg)

I tried adding and subtracting the -device usb-ehci,id=ehci option in the startup script to no avail.

I am connecting my webcam to my MacBook Pro using a usb-A to usb-C that supports On-The-Go functionality. I also tried connecting via a usb hub. When I connect using usb hub, Cheese can recognize my camera. However it cannot stream from the camera. This is not because the resolution is too high (I cannot edit the resolution). I read the QEMU documentation. It sounds like usb-hub is not supported.

I really need to get this webcam set up now! Any help is appreciated. And please don't point me to just install driver for FaceTime camera (I have tried most of the online solutions for that to no avail).